# After upgrade to ColdFusion 11 all pages using CFWindow are slow

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am having a problem with all my pages that include `CFWindow` after upgrading to ColdFusion 11. There is a long delay (15 seconds) and then the message -

> Unresponsive Script
>
> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>
> Script: http://*server*/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/ext-all.js:18

This also happens on the test page from the ColdFusion 11 documentation - https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfwindow

Apart from the delay, the page loads and works fine.

Is this a problem with my installation following upgrade or a more general issue?

Comment: Have you applied all 3 updates?

Comment: Did you open the script in the debugger to get more information?

Comment: I can't help you with your `<cfwindow>` issue, but I'll echo @ScottStroz position: you bring this upon yourself because you use `<cfwindow>` *at all*. You really should not use these features of ColdFusion for the precise reason you have encountered: they're flaky, and poorly supported by either Adobe or the community. You should use industry-recognised *client side* approaches to this. There's a Bootstrap example of an equivalent to `<cfwindow>` here: https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/blob/master/chapters/cfwindow/index.md

Comment: This code (https://gist.github.com/daccfml/09498037cd466ab5db4a) works fine for me on ColdFusion 10 and 11. Obviously it's very simple. But this is *by design*. To troubleshoot your issue, build on that, moving towards your OWN situation until it stops working properly. You will have then identified the issue. At which point, post back here with the repro and a more honed question. Voting to close for being too vague (will remove vote if you improve question). Recommended reading: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: CF11 is new version with Update 3. It would appear the problem has gone away on its own! Thanks for everyones help - I will have a look at the alternative to cfwindow.

Comment: This is a problem with firebug/firefox/cf11 - see separate post re cfgrid but delay and error reported here only occur when firebug is on. Firefox 35.0, Firebug 2.0.7, CF 11 Update 3.